# Sorting in java for array only containing 0 and 1

Tags: java, sorting, data-structures

How to sort array

```
int[] A = {0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0}
```

Comment: Arrays.sort? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(byte[])

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use any sorting algorithm to do it. For beginner use bubble sort (easy to understand)
Refer [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort)

```
public static void bubble_srt( int a[], int n ){
  int i, j,t=0;
  for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
    for(j = 1; j < (n-i); j++){
      if(a[j-1] > a[j]){
        t = a[j-1];
        a[j-1]=a[j];
        a[j]=t;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**EDITED**
As @Pradeep Said: You may definitely use Array.sort()

Comment: Please don't reinvent wheel, there is a Arrays.sort() in API

Comment: For interviews generally they don't allow use of APIs. So it's good to ask for optimal solutions.

Answer (score 10):

You can actually sort this array by traversing the array only once.

Here is the snippet of my code:

```
    int arr[] = {1,1,1,1,0,   0,1,0,1,1,1};
    int arrb[] = new int[arr.length];
    int zeroInsertIndex = 0;
    int oneInsertIndex =arrb.length-1;

    for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        if(arr[i] == 1) 
            arrb[oneInsertIndex--] = 1;
        else if (arr[i] == 0) 
            arrb[zeroInsertIndex++] = 0;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<arrb.length;i++)
        System.out.print(arrb[i] + " ");
```

Answer (score 4):

Although Arrays.sort is an obvious, simple, O(n log n) solution, there is an O(n) solution for this special case:

1. Count the number of zeros, zeroCount.
2. Fill the first zeroCount elements with 0, the remaining elements with 1.

This takes just two passes over the array.

More generally, any array with only a small number of distinct values can be sorted by counting how many times each value appears, then filling in the array accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Your array contains only zeros and one so sum all the elements in the array and then reset the array with those many '1's in the end and rest '0's in the beginning. Time complexity is also O(n) with constant space. So it seems the best and easy one.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] A = { 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0 };
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++)
        sum = sum + A[i];

    Arrays.fill(A, A.length - sum, A.length, 1);
    Arrays.fill(A, 0, A.length - sum, 0);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(A));

  }
```

Try this I implemented the above algorithm.

Output:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Arrays.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28int%5B%5D%29) method from `Arrays` class:

```
int[] A = {0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0};
Arrays.sort(A);
System.out.println(A);
```

Comment: My mistake I have not posted in proper way. I don't want to use collections shorting methods like Arrays.sort. I want to use any data structure to sort it.

Comment: @SanjeevYadav : you mean you want to write your own sorting algorithm?

Comment: Yes Bhavik. Only You got it right. I already know the the various ways of sorting, which I got as reply.... Any way thanks to all answers.

Answer (score 1):

Actually standard off-the-shelf sorting algorithms will typically work on O(n*log(n)). You could just run through the array once adding all the values (i.e. the number of 1). Let's say you put this in `count1`.  Then go once more over the array setting the first `count1` positions to 1, and the rest to 0. It takes 2n steps.

Of course, as other posters said: this kind of optimizations is what you do once you've detected a bottleneck, not right off the bat when you start.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays.sort(A,Collections.reverseOrder());

Comment: For ascending order, just skip the second argument.

Answer (score 0):

USE

```
 Arrays.sort(A);
```

method to sort your array.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this also

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int inputArray[] = { 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0 };
    formatInputArray(inputArray);

}

private static void formatInputArray(int[] inputArray) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
        if (inputArray[i] == 0) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    // System.out.println(count);
    for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
        if (i < count) {
            inputArray[i] = 0;
        }

        else {
            inputArray[i] = 1;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(inputArray[i] + " , ");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Sort Array which contains only 0,1 and 2

```
import java.util.*;
public class HelloWorld {

static void sort012(int []a, int length) {
    int start = 0;
    int mid = 0;
    int end = length - 1;
    int temp;
    while(mid<=end) {
        switch(a[mid]) {
            case 0:
                temp = a[start];
                a[start] = a[mid];
                a[mid] = temp;
                start++;
                mid++;
                break;
            case 1:
                mid++;
                break;
            case 2: 
              temp = a[end];
                a[end] = a[mid];
                a[mid] = temp;
                end--;
                break;
        }


    }

}

 public static void main(String []args){
     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
     int n = sc.nextInt();

    int a[] = new int[n];
    for (int i =0;i<n; i++)
    a[i] = sc.nextInt();

     HelloWorld.sort012(a, n);
    // Print the sorted Array
    for (int i =0;i<n; i++)
    System.out.println(a[i]);

 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var binaryArr = [1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0];

//i - starting index
//j - ending index
function binarySort(arr){
   var i=0,j=arr.length-1;
   for(;i!=j;){
       if(arr[i] == 1){
           if(arr[j] == 0){
               arr[i] = 0;
               arr[j] = 1;
               j--;
               i++;
           } else {
               j--;
           }
       }else{
         i++;
       }
   }
}
binarySort(binaryArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Team 
Please consider the below program in Swift in o(n) time complexity and constant extra space.

import UIKit

var inputArray = [1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1]

var leftIndex: Int = 0
var rightIndex: Int = inputArray.count-1

while leftIndex < rightIndex{

    while inputArray[leftIndex] == 0 && leftIndex < rightIndex{
        leftIndex = leftIndex+1
    }

    while inputArray[rightIndex] == 1 && rightIndex > leftIndex {
        rightIndex = rightIndex-1
    }

    if leftIndex <  rightIndex{
        inputArray[leftIndex] = 0
        inputArray[rightIndex] = 1
        leftIndex = leftIndex+1
        rightIndex = rightIndex-1
    }
}

print(inputArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort 0 and 1 array using below code:

```
public static int[] sortArray(int[] array){
        int first = 0;
        int last = array.length-1;
        while(first<last){
            if(array[first]==0){
                first++;
            }else if(array[last] == 0){
                int temp = array[last];
                array[last] = array[first];
                array[first] = temp;
                first++;
            }else{
                last--;
            }
        }
        return array;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void sort(int a[]) {
        int sum=0;
        int b[]= new int [a.length];
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
            sum=sum+a[i];
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
        int j=b.length-1;
        while(sum>0) {
            b[j]=1;
            sum--;
            j--;
        }
        
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));

    }
```

Comment: Please add comments to your code to explain it. It may help future visitors to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0};
    int start = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == 0) {
            arr[start] = 0;
            if (i != start) {  // should not override same value with 1
                arr[i] = 1;
            }
            start++;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
    }
 }
}
```

//complexity is O(n)

Answer (score 0):

If its just `0`'s and `1`'s, it can be done using two pointers.

c# code snippet :

```
int i = 0; int j = input.Length - 1;

while (i < j)
{
    if (input[i] == 0 && input[j] == 0)
    i++;
    else if(input[i] == 1 && input[j] == 1)
    j--;
    else if (input[i] > input[j])
    {
        input[i++] = 0;
        input[j--] = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        i++; j--;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

int[] a = {0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0}

Here, we are iterating with i where i starts from 1. so we can compare previous index value with the current value of i. Used swapping technique to sort the array.

**Note:** Sort/2 pointer technique we can also use.

```
public int[] sort(int[] a){
  int temp=0;
  for(int i=1;i<a.length;i++){
   if( a[i-1] > a[i]){
    temp = a[i-1];
    a[i-1] = a[i];
    a[i] = temp;
  }
 }
return a[i];
}
```

Time complexity : O(n)

Comment: A good answer should always include an explanation.

Comment: Thanks Sven for your feedback. I have added the comment

Answer (score -1):

The following code will sort your array. Please notice that it does so in place - so it modifies the object in memory instead of returning a new one.

**In Python**

```
arr=[0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0]
arr.sort()
print(arr)
```

**In Java**

```
public class test{
public static void main(String[] args){
int[] arr= {0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0};
Arrays.sort(arr); 
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}}
```

Comment: You should write you example in Java SE, similiar to:
        int[] arr= {0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0};
        Arrays.sort(arr);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));

Comment: Code only answers are generally frowned upon. Please add some explanation as to what your code is achieving